# Configure Long run process using Spring Application Context & lmax disruptors

Tags: spring, lmax

We have a project that needs long run process to check whether payment has been complied, if so record has to promoted to the next level.
Since they are huge number of records to process we decided to use lmax disruptor. 
What are the options? that we can integrate lmax with Spring Application Context?

Comment: Is there a question hidden in there?

Comment: yes, I have added questions.. thanks for reply....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add bean to Context xml and make lazy-load="false"

```xml
<bean id="noticeReminderBatchProcessorApi" class="lk.scandium.spring.batch.lmax.NoticeReminderBatchProcessor" init-method="init"
          destroy-method="destroy" lazy-init="false"
          p:numberOfThreads="1"
          p:queueWarnLimit="5"/>
```

2. 

```java
private final ExecutorService EXECUTOR = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    private Disruptor<TransactionEvent> disruptor;
    private RingBuffer<TransactionEvent> ringBuffer;

    @Autowired
    private PaymentCompletionHandler paymentCompletionHandler;
    private String numberOfThreads;
    private String queueWarnLimit;

    public void processTransaction(PaymentProcessBridge paymentProcessBridge) {
        long sequence = ringBuffer.next();  // Grab the next sequence
        TransactionEvent transactionEvent = ringBuffer.get(sequence);
        transactionEvent.setPaymentProcessBridge(paymentProcessBridge);
        ringBuffer.publish(sequence);
    }
```

3. 

```java
public void init() {
        disruptor = new Disruptor<TransactionEvent>(
                TransactionEvent.EVENT_FACTORY,
                1024,
                EXECUTOR,
                ProducerType.SINGLE,
                new SleepingWaitStrategy());

        disruptor.handleEventsWith(paymentCompletionHandler);
        ringBuffer = disruptor.start();
    }
```